# Error creating the first project in Android Studio

Tags: android

I just started learning Android programming.
I encountered the following errors in making the first project
Open single error
please guide me

[image]

Comment: check your dependencies in gradle file and make sure you have a working internet connection while guild build is taking place.

Comment: I checked. Internet connection is working. I closed the Android studio several times and reopened but I encountered an error.

Comment: you can try changing the appcombat versions in gradle file. Make sure your gradle is compatible with the appcombat versions

Comment: How should I do this?I'm new to Android programming

Comment: open you gradle file check for appcombat version there

Comment: I will install the app TeamViewer

Comment: Connect to my system?

Comment: No I cant I dont have TeamViewer downloaded. You can change app combat version in build.gradle file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Project Sync failed in Android Studio 2.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447360/gradle-project-sync-failed-in-android-studio-2-3-1)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Gradle is in offline mode. Either you were not connected while compiling or Android Studio was not able to connect. So it can't resolve dependencies automatically.

Go to Preferences -> Gradle, and uncheck the option for offline work. Close Android Studio, connect to the internet, open it again, clean the project and then re-run.

Comment: Also refrain from asking questions without doing your homework. There is already a same question on this site with the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447360/gradle-project-sync-failed-in-android-studio-2-3-1